# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, service, autowired

hi guys my springboot version is '2.2.4.RELEASE'.
I wanna autowire 2 parameter in constructor. but it doesn't working.
Mabye i think 'passwordEncoder' has a problem...

here is 'UserService.java' code.

```
import kr.co.loosie.foody.domain.User;
import kr.co.loosie.foody.domain.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    public User registerUser(String email, String name, String password) {
        Optional<User> existed = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (existed.isPresent()) {
            throw new EmailExistedException(email);
        }

        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);

        User user = User.builder()
            .email(email)
            .name(name)
            .password(encodedPassword)
            .level(1L)
            .build();
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public User authenticate(String email, String password) {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EmailNotExistedException(email));

        if (!passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
            throw new PasswordWrongException();
        }

        return user;
      }
}
```

the error part is here.

```
@Autowired
public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
}
```

it's worked when i used only UserReposiotory to get autowired
but I put the **PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder** line , it's not worked.
plz give me some help!

this is warning message

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with         
name 'userService' defined in file [D:\CCC\intellij_ex\foody\foody-customer- 
api\build\classes\java\main\kr\co\loosie\foody\application\UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 
'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' available: expected at least 1 bean 
which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

plz give me some help!

Comment: Not sure that a default `PasswordEncoder` bean is provided by spring framework. You probably have to provide a bean to specify which `PasswordEncoder` implementation you want to use (`BCryptPasswordEncoder` f.ex.) example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt)

Comment: thank u for ur help! I forgot the 2. Define the Password Encoder part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message shows there is no bean for `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder`, which means you haven't defined it anywhere.

You would need something like:

```
@Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

In your configuration (if configuration through Java)

Comment: Thank you so much! I put it in the my Config.java class and it worked.